# PDF files in postgreSQL but using a text field

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, file-upload

I am using ReactJS and some related libraries to upload pdf files.

I have a database with a table called files used to store files. the most important columns are:

```
fileId  character varying(250) NOT NULL,
data    text
```

Every time I upload a pdf file the next commands are executed:

```
 ...

import com.appliedscala.event_models.{FileRecord, FileRecords}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

....
....
       val fileBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(file.ref.file.getPath))
       val fileType = file.contentType.getOrElse("None")
       val encodedFile:String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes)
       val record:FileRecord = FileRecord(UUID.randomUUID().toString, getElement(userid), file.filename, getElement(category),getElement(project), "1",fileType,encodedFile,0)
  FileRecords.add(record)
```

So, the data of that file gets uploaded and I am able to download it. However, I want to do the same using a SQL Insert command (doesn't matter if the data type for the data column is text) so I can place the data of any pdf file in that Data column. How can this be done?

Comment: It's a really bad practice to load the entire PDF file into a byte array and then send it at once to the server. You should seriously consider streaming.

Comment: streaming? never heard of that... Is it valid to use with Java Script ES2015?